# Using Clear parser for semantic role labeling

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, sharpnlp

I want to use the Clear Parser for extract semantic role label of the input sentence. I downloaded the jar file [here](https://code.google.com/p/clearparser/) but I don't know how to use this jar file.

I search on the web but there isn't good guideline for using it.

Please help me to solve this problem (My project is in eclipse on windows).

Answer (score 0):

Mind that Clearparser is now [ClearNLP](https://code.google.com/p/clearnlp/). For an idea how to use the ClearNLP API, check out the DemoNLPDecoder linked from their project page. In fact, that's a small runnable application to which you pass all the models as command line arguments, along with an input and a output file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read the [google link](https://code.google.com/p/clearnlp/wiki/Installation) of ClearNLP and download the jar file. The models that clearNLP use them should be jar file but the [models](https://code.google.com/p/clearnlp/wiki/TrainedModels) are .tgz. how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Download them. You'll find that they are actually ZIP files (JAR files are ZIP files). Rename them to end in .jar and you are good. I have absolutely no idea why they have the ending ".tgz" on the ClearNLP wiki.